# Avoid making duplicate queries in ActiveRecord - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have piece of code with a few simple queries and I am trying to optimize it by compacting them into one single query. But I have no idea how.

```
posts = Post.where(category: "article")
num_posts = posts.count
first_post = posts.first
posts_with_updated_name = posts.map { |post| post[:name] = "UPDATE_" + post[:name] }
```

What I wished, was to have a single query that will be performed on the first line and then **posts** be an array on which to perform the operations on lines 2, 3 and 4. Instead, what I get is that I have 3 separate queries. Any idea how to optimize this into a single query?

LE: You can assume that `num_posts`, `first_post` and `posts_with_updated_name` are just variables that I'm going to need later on

Comment: What the second and third lines for?

Comment: @mechnicov Updated the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well, but I think you want to transform the ActiveRecord collection into an array? If that's so, you can do it with `posts = Post.where(category: "article").to_a`

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I asked for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndreiRS It should be noted though that `.to_a` and `.map` will eager-load all of the Post records into memory (RAM & Swap), which may cause out-of-memory crashes for a very big database. An alternative would be to use [`find_each`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each)

Answer (score 2):

Because converting an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object into an `Array` can potentially consume high amount of memory (and may even ran out of memory) for a big database, I would do the following, which would still use (2 + number-of-batches) SQL queries, but that your application would scale in the long-run.

```
posts = Post.where(category: "article")
num_posts = posts.count
first_post = posts.first

# || is a PostgreSQL operator for string concatenation
# if you are using MySQL check out CONCAT instead
posts_with_updated_name = posts.select('posts.*', "'UPDATE_' || name AS updated_name")

# example usage
posts_with_updated_name.find_each do |post|
  puts post.id
  puts post.name
  puts post.updated_name
end

# example output:
# 6
# 'Spider Man is Back'
# 'UPDATE_Spider Man is Back'
# 84
# 'Hello World'
# 'UPDATE_Hello World'
```

### Recommended Solution

#### 1. Temporary "Updated Name"

I wouldn't store the "updated name" into the variable, but that I will append/prepend the string only by demand, as follows:

```
posts = Post.where(category: "article")
num_posts = posts.count
first_post = posts.first

# somewhere in your code where you are actually already gonna be looping over `posts`
posts.find_each do |post|
  updated_name = "UPDATE_#{post.name}'"
  # do something here about updated name
end
```

#### 2. Permanent "Updated Name"

Or... if this "Updated Name" value is a permanent logic across the application, then just simply write a method in the model:

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def updated_name
    "UPDATE_#{name}"
  end
end
```

Then in your code you'll just do the following without the need of setting up the value for "updated name",

```
posts = Post.where(category: "article")
num_posts = posts.count
first_post = posts.first

# example:
puts first_post.updated_name
# => 'UPDATE_Hello World'
```